# Is sharing information believable to minimise losses in a fake interstellar war?

Tags: warfare

Once upon a time two kingdoms of starfaring civilizations were forced to fight a war by external forces. They wanted to minimise losses on both sides by sharing information in secret. One side was much stronger than the other. They know that they are being monitored but not how.
Both sides use traversable wormholes for travel and war. One kingdom has more citizens and natural resources. They have the same level of technology. This means high energy weapons and large starships. Is it believable that sharing information in secret is enough to minimise losses? Their populations are in the order of billions so thousands of deaths due to this war are deemed acceptable.

Comment: Believability is down to you the writer and how you frame it and approach it - which is in the writing process, not the worldbuilding one. We have a stack for that: [writing.se]. Be sure to take their tour, read--up in their help centre about what's on-topic etc..

Comment: I read something in the line of this, the two civilizations in question were only fighting around dead worlds. There were war casualties, but no or almost no civilians died. So the general answer to your question is a yes, especially if both sides only see that war as an obligation instead of a thing they want to win.

Comment: I don't find the premise believable. If they are at war, why would they want to minimise losses *and still be at war*? They could call a truce or otherwise cease hostilities. Being at an active war and officially supplying the enemy with information is at odds with one another.

Comment: What exactly do these external forces want? Do they just want a state of war to exist, or do they want casualties, or big battles or territory changing hands?

Comment: This sounds like the basis of Star Trek Original Series episode 23: A Taste of Armageddon, except that in this case, the governments are directly colluding to eliminate the horrible side-effects of war, while still killing people. I have to agree that the answer to the question is 100% dependent upon how good the author is.

Comment: I find the grammar of your title unnatural and difficult to make sense of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## If you're being forced to fight, you can get your losses to zero.

Just send drone ships to fight your wars. Since you're not being obliged to take territory or do anything except fight, whoever has more ships will presumably win the war.

Comment: Drone ships can be full of various machines that scream piteously, in case malicious outside forces are listening.   Or in case you have a lot of those machines and you would like to send them off in a drone ship because they never quit screaming piteously and the kids need to sleep.

Comment: You can do whatever you want with your drone ships, including making every robot inside a legal citizen if they require a certain amount of civilian deaths, or yeah making them die painful deaths in space if the overwatchers desire that.

Answer (score 2):

Use ships with personel in back and drone swarms with weapons in front line.

If have spies on other side then can have "bad security" on booth sides to "steal" comunication protocols for drones.

Battle will be without any shot to command ships only hacking opposite side drones till all drones be fired - by hackers or by fire.
When no drones left then command ships with personel will withdraw.

Make it right and no casulaties will be.

Answer (score 2):

**War plans to inflict maximum damage**

When countries are at war, they make war plans to inflict maximum damage on the enemy. But if war plans are leaked or stolen, the enemy makes safety measures before hand and losses are reduced.

Sometimes, a country sends fake war plans to the enemy as deception operation to disguise some other task e.g [Operation Mincemeat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Mincemeat) in WW-II

> The full effect of Operation Mincemeat is not known, but Sicily was
> liberated more quickly than anticipated and losses were lower than
> predicted.

**Sharing war plans to reduce losses**

One kingdom can inform the other about their war plans e.g. they can tell the other, "we shall bomb this area at this time". The other kingdom will shift all the people to some other safe place. If building are destroyed, they can be built again.

Comment: Countries at war rarely try and inflict maximum damage on the enemy, for many reasons. Nuclear, biological and chemical weapons aren't used for fear of consequences from third parties. Attacks on civilians are often avoided because of the Geneva Convention, and because it makes it harder to passify the inhabitants after conquest. Historically, many wars were fought between armies with costs to non-military targets limited to pillaging for supplies. The Iraq War of 2002 was fought to depose Saddam Hussein, and any damage to Iraq was an unwanted side-effect.

Comment: In fact, some countries used total destruction as a defense against an offensive invasion force.  Salt the Earth tactics are designed to make the ceded territory so utterly useless to the enemy that they need to further extend supply lines deeper into enemy territory.  Russia/USSR is famous for this tactic and used it to bring a halt to two separate European dictators who tore through the remainder of the continent (Napoleon and Hitler).  As a rule, less than swift invasions tend to end in defeat for the invading forces because due to war of attrition.

Comment: @imtaar I used the word depose, not kill. As for the brutality of the man, the Human Rights Watch article dismissing humanitarian goals for the war in Iraq says "we estimate that in the last twenty-five years of Ba`th Party rule the Iraqi government murdered or "disappeared" some quarter of a million Iraqis, if not more." The point is, the US intended no more damage to Iraq than needed to complete its goals.

Answer (score 1):

Given human history, it is not believable that *both* sides will want to minimize losses. The weaker side always has an interest in maximizing casualties as that’s generally the only way to get the greater power to the negotiation table — it is the point of war.